# What will be happen if you dynamically allocates memory for one object of the class as an argument?

Tags: c++, dynamic, new-operator

```
class Example
{
  private:
   Example* pointer;
   Example* pointer2;
  public:
   Example();
   void setPointer2(Example* object);
};

Example::Example()
{
  pointer = new Example();
}

void Example::setPointer2(Example* object)
{
  this->pointer2 = object;
}

int main()
{
  Example object;
  object.setPointer2(new Example());

  return 0;
}
```

Delete is not important. I just want to know what is the differences between this two object which is adresses holding by pointer and pointer2. Are they differently allocated? The actual question is, does it matter where to use the "new" operator?

Comment: Working with pointers and manual memory access is a large and complex subject. 
 For your benefit I suggest you get a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read up on what it has to say on the subject.  There should be at least a chapter dedicated to this in the beginners books.

Comment: You ... wrote an infinitely recursive constructor. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: Yeah, it's just pointless. I could write another class for that. I just wondering my question.

Comment: IMO a strange question you're asking.  Other than the recursive constructor issue, why would it matter where `new` is eventually called to create an `Example`?  Maybe where it's called would be "bad design", but nothing stops a routine from issuing the call to `new`.  It's just another request to create an object dynamically, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Kaepxer I understand that the recursive allocation is not relevant to your question, but it is so strange to read that it diverts attention from your real question. You should consider using a simple `int` for the example.

Comment: According to "does it matter where to use the "new"?". From my point of view it is better to call "new" and corresponding "delete" in the same logical part of a code. For example: in the same function; or in the same class with new allocation of memory in copy constructor and than copying of the content. Because if you call "new" in some logical part of a code and than call "delete" for this memory in the other logical part of the code than in some complex case somebody can forget to free the memory (memory leak occurs). To avoid such situation it's better to localize of using "new"-"delete".

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé You're right. But I got my answer. Sergey that's an another perspective to my question but I will consider that too. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A major problem you have in your code is ***infinite recursion***! The constructor you have defined:

```cpp
Example::Example()
{
  pointer = new Example();
}
```

creates a new object of its own type. This will call the constructor (again), and that call will call the constructor (again and again...)

But, other than that issue, it doesn't really matter whether you create a `new` object by directly assigning its address to `pointer` or if you create the object elsewhere and then assign its address (later) to `pointer2`. Both will point to an object of the class.

Comment: It does matter, in terms of design, because whether the _ownership_ is clear (and correctly interpreted) will depend on it. But I realise you weren't coming at this from a design angle.

Comment: Ownership is important.  Raw owning pointers are dangerous and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @Lightness A very good point! But, in terms of the OP's question, there is no *existential* difference between the two pointers.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Yepper 